# JQuery, Ajax submit with Mysqli validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

How can I submit a form dynamically where I run mysqli to check if an email exists. If it exists, echo an error ALL DYNAMICALLY.

I would like to run a jquery ajax submit but echo out php errors. I can submit but nothing will echo.

```
function DYNAMIC_CHECK(X)
    {       
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>',
            type:'POST',
            data:X,
        });
    }
```

X is the formdata. It all works, but the PHP echo will not show up nor will any  vars that are created and echoed out throughout the page as errors.

```
if(isset($_POST['REGISTER']))
{       
    $COUNT = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($CON, "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE EMAIL='$EMAIL'"));

    if($COUNT == 1) { $EMAIL_ERROR='EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS'; }
}

echo $EMAIL_ERROR;
```

Is this possible to dynamically show $EMAIL_ERROR?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shorthand function [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) which sends the serialized data of the form and returns the result into a variable.

```
$.post( "test.php", $( this ).serialize(), function ( data ) {
 ...what to do with data (returns the result of test.php)...
});
```

Comment: exactly, then you can have something like if (data.trim() == 'EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS') {//do something}

Comment: Good idea @Ehsan.  To the OP: Since you asked about "AJAX" you should be looking into a returning XML rather than plain text.  For example "<error>Email Already Exists</email>" then use Jquery/JS to look into the error node, for example using the find() in jquery.

Comment: To get this straight,.. This will serialize the data that is created by the ajax submit, and make it usable. So it will make $EMAIL_ERROR usable for a jquery alert or something?

Comment: How can I alert the $EMAIL_ERROR using jquery or whatever using this?

Comment: @MaciekSemik Well first you would want to check if the user should be alerted by using something like Ehsan has.  Then you can alert using the data variable.  this stands for your form, so this.serialize will serialize your form data and send it to test.php in this example.  data will contain the result from test.php.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But to lets say alert(EMAIL_ERROR); how do I do this? function(data) { alert(data.EMAIL_ERROR); }

Comment: data contains what is returned.  So you would just use data if you are returning it in plain text.  You aren't using "AJAX" if you use plain text like that though.  AJAX means Javascript and XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your ajax function to display result from the request.

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        url:'<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>',
        type:'POST',
        data:X,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

The echo of the request will be returned in the `data` variable in the `success:` function. Use the `alert(data)` to see what info is returned from the request.

Comment: I don't get anything from this. alert(data); gives me nothing

Comment: This means that the page doesn't return anything ? try to put an `Else` statement and fill your $EMAIL_ERROR with something else if you don't find anything (ex: 'NO ERROR')  or just echo a simple string `echo 'hello world'` anywhere on the page.. it should be displayed in the alert(data). You can then do whatever with this info.